# If $\hat{\theta}$ is consistent, does it mean that the limit of $var(\hat{\theta})$ when $n$ tends to $\infty$ is $0$?

Tags: statistics

Suppose that $\hat{\theta}$ is an estimator based on an idd random sample $X_1$, ..., $X_n$ with $var(\hat{\theta}) < \infty$ for all $n$.

If $\hat{\theta}$ is consistent, does it mean that $\lim_{n\to\infty} var(\hat{\theta}) = 0$?

Comment: Just FYI: You can use MathJax in the title as well.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Firstly, $\operatorname{var}(\hat \theta)$ is infinite if $E[X_1^4]=\infty$. This cannot converge to zero.

Secondly, even if the variance is finite, the convergence is not guaranteed. We are talking about relation between convergence of random variables (consistency) and that of their expectations. You need uniform integrability (under $P_\theta$ for each $\theta$) of $\hat\theta^2$ to deduce the latter from the former.

Comment: "We are talking about relation between convergence of random variables (consistency) and that of their expectations." More precisely, we are talking about convergence in probability (aka consistency) vs. mean square convergence (aka convergence of the variance to zero).